# function that reads a 2d array in c++

Tags: c++, g++

I'm trying to write a function that reads a 2D array of integers where the user is the one who enters the size of the array (it shouldn't be defined before ) . I tried this but it's not working.
I appreciate your help!

[image]
line 6 is the declaration of the function 
 this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Fill_table(int mat[][], int s) {
    for (int i = 0; i<s; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<s; j++) {
            cout << "mat[" << i << "][" << j << "]:" << endl;
            cin >> mat[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;

    cout << "Enter the size:  ";
    cin >> n;

    int a[n][n];
    Fill_table(a, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***I tried this but it's not working.*** Please elaborate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing 2-D array as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990568/passing-2-d-array-as-argument)

Comment: In the future, it's much better to paste the error as text instead of an image.  There's a lot missing. But, your problem should be solved by the above comment.

Comment: Because your size is not known at compile time -- look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new

Comment: Another alternative is to use [a simple matrix class.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the size of a multidimensional array at runtime.
The error

> error: declaration of ‘mat’ as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first
>   `void Fill_table(int mat[][], int s)`

tells you exactly that.

Consider using C++ data structure instead, in this case `vector<vector<int>>`, you have a somewhat simple how-to guide in [Creating a Matrix using 2D vector in C++ – Vector of Vectors](https://thispointer.com/creating-a-matrix-using-2d-vector-in-c-vector-of-vectors/).

Comment: Note that what's being called a 2D `vector` is actually a `vector` of `vector`s and can be a surprisingly slow solution due to extra pointer chasing and lack of contiguity between the rows. It's not so bad with a large matrix, but with a small matrix, the inability to take full advantage of caching can be murderous. [Here's an alternative that uses one `vector` and a bit of indexing math.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301)

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you a simple alternative. Instead of declaring a 2D array with [][], you could use `[n*n]` and then subscript with `i*s + j`.  The code would be

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Fill_table(int* mat, int s) {
    for (int i = 0; i<s; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<s; j++) {
            cout << "mat[" << i << "][" << j << "]:" << endl;
            cin >> mat[i*s+j];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;

    cout << "Enter the size:  ";
    cin >> n;

    int a[n * n];
    Fill_table(a, n);
    return 0;
}
```

1D arrays can be passed as a pointer to a function.  You also need to pass the size (as you did).  For 2D arrays, you need to know the size at compile time.

Comment: Caveats: `int a[n * n];` is a non-Standard Variable Length Array and may not be supported by your compiler. If it is supported, you need to restrict the values of `n` the user can provide since `n*n` gets big fast. An `n` of as little as 500 could exhaust the available Automatic storage on a desktop PC.